# How can I create a table with standalone class?

Tags: tables, captions, tabularx, standalone

When I use the `‎‎‎\documentclass{standalone}‎`, there is an error in my output PDF file. There is a white page with the table in the PDF, but I want the corrupted one.

How can I fix the problem?

```
‎‎‎\documentclass[tightpage]{standalone}‎
    ‎\usepackage{tabularx}‎‎
    ‎\usepackage{caption}‎
    ‎\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}‎ 
    ‎\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{} C @{}}{#1}}‎ 
    ‎\begin{document}‎
    ‎\begin{table}‎
            ‎\centering‎‎
            ‎‎\caption{ssss}‎‎
    ‎\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C CCC C CCCC}‎
     ‎& \multicolumn{5}{c}{‎N‎} &  \\ 
    ‎W & 7 & 9 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 1 \\ \hline‎
    ‎0.6078 & 1.0592 (4)& 1.0646 (4) & 1.0647 (6) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 \\‎ 
    ‎1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    ‎\end{tabularx}‎
    ‎\end{table}‎
    ‎\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code contains several strange character, and I cannot compile it. However, I am wondering how much sense a float like `table` might make sense in `standalone`, where is it supposed to float? Likewise, what value do you think `\textwidth` has, which you use in `tabularx`?

Comment: Moreover you have `\Centering`: is it a new command of yours or do you mean `\centering`?

Comment: After removing the strange characters and `\begin{table} \centering \caption{ssss}` as well as `\end{table}`, and fixing `\Centering`, as pointed out by @CarLaTeX, your code compiles without problems. The text width is then set to `345.0pt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't completely understand your question, but I think you're misusing `standalone`.

There's no sense in using a floating environment (`table`) with this document class.

I would do this way: create a `standalone` with your table only, let's call it `mytable.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{array}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c ccc c cccc}
     & \multicolumn{5}{c}{N} &  \\ 
    W & 7 & 9 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 1 \\ \hline
    0.6078 & 1.0592 (4)& 1.0646 (4) & 1.0647 (6) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

with this output `mytable.pdf`:

[image]

and then include the `.pdf` in your main document in a floating environment, in this way:

```
\documentclass{book}% book is just an example
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{ssss}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mytable.pdf}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, it would be better to use a smaller font size for the table, so that it is not resized. For example with `\small`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{array}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

    \begin{document}\small% or what you prefer
    \begin{tabular}{c ccc c cccc}
     & \multicolumn{5}{c}{N} &  \\ 
    W & 7 & 9 & 13 & 17 & 19 & 1 \\ \hline
    0.6078 & 1.0592 (4)& 1.0646 (4) & 1.0647 (6) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 (5) & 1.0647 \\ 
    1.0012 & 1.1614 (7) & 1.1666 (4) & 1.1668 (6) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 (5) & 1.1668 \\ 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

and the main without `[width=\textwidth]`:

```
\documentclass{book}% book is just an example
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{ssss}
\includegraphics{mytable.pdf}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output of the main:

[image]